# how to create a new interlaced image to two picture with python opencv and anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

[image]

I would like to create a new interlaced image where the odd rows belong to one image and the even rows to the other image.  I am trying to do that with python and openCv and numpy! Reading the one images and with a loop i try to write the values in the odd and even rows.  I don't know how to do that. Do you have some tips?p

Comment: what is "strong text" at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: I think op is getting familiar with the formatting tools in the stack site..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


imgshape = (100,100,3)

blue = np.zeros(imgshape)
red = np.zeros(imgshape)
blue[:,:,2] = np.ones(blue.shape[:2])
red[:,:,0] = np.ones(blue.shape[:2])

mix = np.zeros(imgshape)

oddrows = [i for i in range(blue.shape[0]) if i %2==1]
evenrows = [i for i in range(blue.shape[0]) if i%2==0]

mix[oddrows] = red[oddrows]
mix[evenrows] = blue[evenrows]

plt.imshow(mix)
```